# Running for-in loop with mongodb operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have some function like this...

```
for(key in object){
    db.collection.findOne(criteria, function(err, doc){
        // ...
        db.collection.update(...);
    })
};
```

However, the value of key changes before the mongodb calls are complete, i.e. the loop goes into next iteration. Is there a way to do it in sequential manner. Or is there something for objects like `async.map()` for arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the calls to your callback will happen after all the iterations of the loop have taken place, so when they get executed the value of `key` will be whatever is its last value.

One common solution is to wrap all your calls in a closure:

```
for(key in object){
    (function(key, value) {
        db.collection.findOne(criteria, function(err, doc){
            // ...
            db.collection.insert(...);
        })
    })(key, object[key]);
};
```

Another way you could achieve the same thing is to use the `Object.keys()` method (which creates an array out of the keys in your object) and call `Array#forEach` on the array. That way you can skip the extra closure because forEach already has a function callback:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
    db.collection.findOne(criteria, function(err, doc){
        // ...
        db.collection.update(...);
    })
});
```

Which is arguably a bit more elegant

Comment: Thanks! Went with the `Object.keys()` option!

Answer (score 1):

You could build up a closure to save the value of key

```
for(key in object){
  (function(ky) { 
    db.collection.findOne(criteria, function(err, doc){
        // ...
        db.collection.insert(...);
    })
  })(key)
};
```

Comment: It's called a "closure". Clojure is a programming language :)

Comment: oops, been writing too much clojure lately.